# Mysql Query not returning true values as concatenated string

Tags: mysql

I want to get only true values columns and its value as string...

```
id | a | b | c | d | e
------------------------
5  | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0
```

I tried this,

```
select CONCAT( 'a:', a, ',b:', b, ',c:', c, ',d:', d, ',e:',e  ) where id=5
```

While run above query i got result as **a:1,b:0,c:1,d:1,e:0**

But wan't result in below format..

```
a:1,b:1,d:1
```

Just wan't to get only true values.. can any one please..

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want some other thing oriented this. I just specified example here..

Comment: Are the fields boolean?

Comment: I know. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Elin yes boolean values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix of CONCAT and CONCAT_WS.

```
select CONCAT_WS( ',', 
                    IF(a = 0, NULL, CONCAT('a:', a)), 
                    IF(b = 0, NULL, CONCAT('b:', b)), 
                    IF(c = 0, NULL, CONCAT('c:', c)), 
                    IF(d = 0, NULL, CONCAT('d:', d)), 
                    IF(e = 0, NULL, CONCAT('e:', e)) ) where id=5
```

CONCAT_WS will skip null values. Hence when the value is false / 0 it uses null to force that value to be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multiple case within CONCAT() like:

```
CONCAT (case when a <> '0' then CONCAT ('a:', a) else '' end case, ...)
```

This should help you.

Comment: I try this and let you know shortly

Comment: Just check the match condition "a <> '0'". You might need to change it as per your requirement.